# Writing a topic pub/sub system

Tags: c#, networking, asynchronous

I am writing a client/server application that will publish and subscribe to topics. 
I have few questions about the architecture and the implementation for this project.

First to setup the basis i will use c# ( .NET 3.5 ) and i want to explicitly use raw Sockets/AIO/Threads(No WCF at first as i do want to fine tune the server and clients to my needs ). Clients mostly subscribe to topics but may occasionally send command to the server and even publish data . Some clients may be publishers only as well.

1. What do you think should be the
   basic building blocks of my server (
   threads per client , iocp,  .... ).
2. Should client use the same
   NetworkStream to listen subscribed
   topics and send command/publish to
   the server? How to wait for data and
   at the same time write data to the
   stream , should this be done in the
   same thread ?

(sample code will be appreciated :) )

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Why not use MSMQ (`System.Messaging`)?  Or something like [CodeMesh](http://www.codemesh.com/products/jmscourier/examples/topic_pub_cs.html)?

Don't mean to troll... Only reason I ask is this problem space is well explored through a lot of products, and there are a lot of hard problems that are solved for your OOTB with this approach.

Comment: Hi cwash , I agree that these applications may actually achieve my goal but i prefer to look at the low level picture to learn the internals and know how to tweak my app and be able to look at the pro and cons of several designs . Furthermore my application need to be able to subscribe to some topics but not all of them. I also need to be able to create some sort of local proxy to save bandwidth and share memory accross many local apps.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would use async sockets as much as possible as it would eliminate the need for you to manage your own thread pool for request handling.
2. The client should use two streams - one for listing and another for sending.  This would greatly simplify things on both the client and server side.  Again, use async sockets to avoid having to manage multiple threads.

Just make sure to be careful managing locking with shared resources used by your async callbacks.  If at all possible, avoid having shared resources as much as possible.  Managine concurrent access to things is usually the worst part of any app like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out ActiveMQ?  I believe it already does topics and C# has the ability to talk to it through their NMS API.

Comment: Yes it already provides that kind of service but i would like to learn more and understand the internal of writing efficient and scalable network server.